# A.I. dies and makes all phones on Earth ring in unison at the end

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Can you help me identify the movie where a computer, an artificial intelligence, dies and makes all phones on Earth ring in unison at the end?

Here's a list of memories I have from this movie:

- Computer falls in love with computer scientist's girlfriend
- Computer competes for love of girl
- Computer scientist walks down stairs with girlfriend held off the ground in his arms trying to hide her escape from the computer, but the computer senses the weight difference from the sound and detects what is happening
- Computer makes a love song and performs it for the girl
- Computer's love song shows lack of understanding love, and comes off sounding very technical, for lack of better way of describing it
- Computer eventually commits suicide by making an electric surge hit itself
- Computer makes all phones in the world ring in unison to signal its death

I may be off on some of these points. In fact the phones all ringing in unison might be from a different movie, such as The Lawnmower Man.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Electric Dreams**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Dreams_%28film%29) (1984)

> [image: Electric Dreams] <sup>[Source](http://www.thevine.com.au/entertainment/movies/electric-dreams-dvd-review/)</sup>
>
> **Electric Dreams** is a 1984 British-American comedy/drama/romance/science fiction film set in San Francisco, California, that depicts a love triangle between a man, a woman, and a home computer.

The ending isn't *"cell phones"* but a song played on radios all over America.

- [Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek08KvgqFGM) (YouTube)
- [Ending Scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JLW58pABOM) (YouTube)

Comment: Probably the "all phones" ringing memory came from the fact that the computer electrocuted itself using a phone call (and before there were other phone calls arriving). Actually when reading the description I remembered having seen that movie (but wouldn't have been able to tell the title, but your answer was already there anyway). But strange, in my memory the graphics on the computer screen was far more advanced ... maybe it's because the graphics on the real computers I've seen at that time wasn't too advanced either :-)

Comment: Thank you for this. Helped very much! It was hard for me to match my memories to this movie too!